# typescript error Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase

Hello so i'm new to typescript react and currently trying to make applications using typescript and tutorial from youtube.

```
const RegisterCustomer: React.FC = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState<string>('');

    const [email, setEmail] = useState<string>('');
    const [username, setUsername] = useState<string>('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState<string>('');
    const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);
    const { register } = useAuth();
    

  return (
   <IonPage>
        <Register />
        <IonContent className="body">
        <IonGrid className="gridinput1">
        </IonGrid>

        <IonGrid className="gridinput2">
        <IonRow>
            <IonInput type="email" className="inputEmail" value={email} placeholder="Email" onIonChange={e => setEmail(e.detail.value!)}></IonInput>
        </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
        <IonGrid className="gridinput3">
        <IonRow>
            <IonInput type="password" className="inputEmail" value={password} placeholder="Password" onIonChange={e => setPassword(e.detail.value!)}></IonInput>
        </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>
        <IonGrid className="gridinput1">
        <IonRow>
            <IonButton onClick={async e =>{
                e.preventDefault()
                const res = await register(email, password);
                if(res) {
                    console.log(res);
                }
                else {
                    //handle null response
                }
                console.log(email, password)
            }} className="buttonLogin" expand="block" size="default" color="new">
                Register Now
            </IonButton>
        </IonRow>
        </IonGrid>   
            <p className="loginSeller"><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/">Are you a seller? Login as Seller</a></p>
    </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default RegisterCustomer;
```

and this is the authContext

```
type ButtonProps = {
    children: ReactNode;
    
}

export const useAuth = () =>useContext(AuthContext);

type AuthContextType = {
    currentUser: null;
    register: (
      email: string,
      password: string
    ) => Promise<UserCredential | undefined>;
  };

const AuthContext = createContext<Partial<AuthContextType>>({}); // Partial

export default function AuthContextProvider( { children}  : ButtonProps){
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

    function register(email: string, password:string) {
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    }
    
    const value = {
        currentUser,
        register,
    }
    
    return <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
}
```

im trying to get the data from register to firebase but i encounter error " Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'. " in register.then in RegisterCustomer page. How do i solve this problem

Comment: Well you have declared the context type to be a `Partial<AuthContextType>` which means all the properties are optional and might be undefined. What would make sense, for your use case, if the `register` function was missing from the context? Or if you feel that `register` should _always_ be present, use a type which keeps that property marked as required. Eg: `Partial<Omit<AuthContextType, "register">> & Pick<AuthContextType, "register">`.

Comment: can you give example how to make it right

Comment: The solution depends on if `register` should always be part of the context or not. If it can be missing, we will conditionally call it to avoid invoking it if it is undefined. If it cannot be missing, we have to adjust the types you are using for the context to show that it is always present. So, which is the case? Is `register` always part of the context, or not? (from your code it looks like you expect it to always exist, can you just confirm that is the case?)

Comment: if i change the code to ```const AuthContext = createContext<Partial<Omit<AuthContextType, "register">>>({})``` i got error in RegisterCustomer page, it says ```Property 'register' does not exist on type 'Partial<Omit<AuthContextType, "register">>'```

Comment: i think its always exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you expect the `register` property to always exist, adjust your types so that it remains as a required property:

```
const AuthContext = createContext<Partial<Omit<AuthContextType, "register">> & Pick<AuthContextType, "register">>({});
```

Here, the type is broken into two pieces. The `Partial<Omit<AuthContextType, "register">>` creates a type that *removes* the `register` property and marks everything else as optional. The `Pick<AuthContextType, "register">` creates a type that *only* has the `register` property. We combine those together using an intersection (`&`) to get the final type which makes everything *except* `register` optional.

---

This will produce an additional error since you are passing `{}` as the default value, but the type indicates that a `register` property *must* be present on that context. Since it is merely the default and you overwrite it when using the provider, I would recommend passing a no-op function to it as the default `register` value. Eg:

```
const AuthContext = createContext<Partial<Omit<AuthContextType, "register">> & Pick<AuthContextType, "register">>({register: async () => undefined});
```

Comment: that clear the previous problem thank you, but another error occur it say ```Type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(email: string, password: string) => Promise<UserCredential | undefined>'.
  Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<UserCredential | undefined>'.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'UserCredential | undefined'.``` is it not possible to fix this ?

Comment: I made an edit just after posting the answer which changes the default to `async () => undefined` instead of `async () => {}`. Did you try with the former version, or the latter?